# karma/jasmine error - No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/

Tags: angularjs, node.js, windows, angular5, karma-jasmine

I am writing unit test for angular(1.6.3) app using vscode on windows machine, while running npm test my chrome browser is not launching, in the terminal i am getting `No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/`

Comment: reload page "http://localhost:9876/"  and immediately save( ctrl + S) any .spec file.

Comment: Open  any browser and go to the address provided. However, do you have your Karma configured to open Chrome? or is it ChromeHEadless? 
Check : `karma.conf.js` `browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],`

Comment: @dream88 i have configured chrome in karma.conf.js

Answer (score 0):

Try declare this environment variable

```
export CHROME_BIN="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
```